# Vagrant Chef cookbook "maven" takes only the last repository

Tags: ruby, maven, chef-infra, vagrant, nexus

Currently I am trying to deploy multiple artifacts from multiple repositories.
The maven cookbook by OPSCODE provides the attribute `node['maven']['repositories']`.
There are six different repos I added, but only [the default](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) and the last are taken. My code looks like this:

```
# Java
default['java']['install_flavor'] = 'oracle'
default['java']['oracle']['accept_oracle_download_terms'] = true
default['java']['jdk_version'] = '7'

# Maven
force_default['maven']['repositories'] =
[
    'http://location1.com/repo',
    'http://location2.com/repo',
    'https://location3.com/repo',
    'http://location4.com/repo1',
    'http://location4.com/repo2'
]
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Show us the code that is supposed to deploy the artefacts.

Comment: This has been fixed in the upstream cookbook. Issues like this should be reported via the Opscode issue tracker at tickets.opscode.com